# Separate servers handling WSDL file differently

Tags: php, linux, web-services, soap, wsdl

Within a project I've been writing for the past two years I have a WSDL file which works nicely for use with my SOAP calls however we are now moving all of our code over to a new server and it seems to handle this differently.

On the old server if I type in the file path for the WSDL file I can simply read it as if it's a text doc, but on the new server it gives me an error:
[image]

EDIT: This does not happen in FireFox but does still not work when I call the webservice.

Now while I understand that using example.org/GetWhatever isn't valid, this will work on my other server. Does anyone know why it tries to render this rather than give me the text? And what is a valid URI?

EDIT: I think this is down to the php install on the server not having everything installed. Does anyone know what I need installed to run php webservices?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be http://example.org/GetTest?wsdl?

Comment: I'm not sure, should it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have written the WSDL by hand.
Well it is very difficult and error phone.

Why do not user nusoap which generates wsld for you!

Comment: You're right, I did - a long time ago. nusoap was my first attempt which didn't seem to work for me. It looks now like there was something up with the server last night as it doesn't show this message anymore! Will report back later ;)